# Combining large dataset by Keycolumns

Tags: sql, t-sql

I **have a dataset** which looks like this:

```
Column1 (PK) | Attribute | Value
1            | Name      | Carl
1            | Jobtitle  | Driver
2            | Name      | Lisa
2            | Age       | 15
3            | Name      | Jon
3            | Age       | 43
3            | Jobtitle  | Programmer
```

---

Since the Attributes are arbitrary they can't be properly atomized in sole columns. The dataset can become and is already huge.

I wanted to have an output which fusions together all attributes in a way that it becomes like this:

**Resultset**

```
Column1 (PK) | FusionedAttributes
1            | Name = Carl, Jobtitle = Driver
2            | Name = Lisa, Age = 15
3            | Name = Jon, Age = 43, Jobtitle = Programmer
```

I have tried my way with UNION and subqueries but I won't come forth. The combination of the results would also be possible in the underlying programming language but for performance reasons I thought it would be great to have SQL-Server doing the work since the engines are in my layman understandings optimized for evaluating huge datasets, much more than the algorithms I'm able to create.

Is there a possibility to do this?

Comment: SQL Server can return the data as complex XML since 2005. SQL Server 2016 added JSON support. Do you *really* want to return the data in this form? JSON or XML would make it a lot easier for clients to work with that data. It would make it easier to query the attribute/value data too

Comment: In any case you probably *shouldn't* use such an EAV schema. SQL Server's sparse columns and XML/JSON storage means you can have thousands of optional rows per table without taking up space, or store complex value objects in fields. An EAV schema can't be indexed or validated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server can return the data as complex XML since 2005. SQL Server 2016 added JSON support. Returning the data in one of those forms will make it easier for client applications to work with it without creating their own parser. It would also allow the values to be used in other T-SQL queries.

Given this table :

```
declare @foo table (
id int,
attribute varchar(20),
value varchar(20)
)

INSERT into @foo
VALUES
(1,'Name', 'Carl'),
(1,'Jobtitle', 'Driver'),
(2,'Name', 'Lisa'),
(2,'Age', '15'),
(3,'Name', 'Jon'),
(3,'Age', '43'),
(3,'Jobtitle  ', 'Programmer')
```

You can retrieve the attributes as XML with :

```
select 
    f1.id, 
    ( select attribute as name,value 
      from @foo attribute 
      where attribute.id=f1.id 
      for xml auto,type,Root('record'))
from @foo f1
group by f1.id
```

This returns :

```
id  DataAsXML
1   <record><attribute name="Name" value="Carl" /><attribute name="Jobtitle" value="Driver" /></record>
2   <record><attribute name="Name" value="Lisa" /><attribute name="Age" value="15" /></record>
3   <record><attribute name="Name" value="Jon" /><attribute name="Age" value="43" /><attribute name="Jobtitle  " value="Programmer" /></record>
```

Comment: I eventually took your answer since it seems to be the most convenient for me :) Thanks for answering and leading me to a way I would aways prefer over this KV notation... Your commentary about avoiding EAV needs to be evaluated for sure

Comment: @mayen you should check the various articles by SQL Server MVPs about this eg [SQL: Design – Entity Attribute Value Tables (Part 1) – Why? by Greg Low](https://blog.greglow.com/2018/02/12/sql-design-entity-attribute-value-tables-part-1/) and [SQL: Design – Entity Attribute Value Tables (Part 2) – Pros and Cons](https://blog.greglow.com/2018/02/19/sql-design-entity-attribute-value-tables-part-2-pros-cons/). Hint: they don't like it

Comment: I will. That's great but data structures which already carry data are often complicated to restructure. If performance bottlenecks something else must be found though. The query you created gives the required results but they are huge^^

Comment: @mayen that's an inherent problem of working with EAV. The only way to *not* produce huge results is to read the data in their EAV form and rehydrate the objects on the client. In SQL Server 2016 you can use JSON which will produce results only slightly larger than what you tried, although they'll look ugly. SQL Server's sparse columns feature removes the need for EAV in most cases - why use EAV when you can have 30K columns per table? Internally the values *are* stored in an XML field, so you only pay for non-NULL values

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this efficiently, but you can do:

```
select c.id,
       stuff( (select concat(', ', attribute, ' = ', value)
               from t t2
               where t2.id = c.id
               for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
              ), 1, 2, ''
            ) as FusionedAttributes 
from (select distinct column1 from t) c;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE table foo (


id int,
attribute varchar(20),
value varchar(20)

)
INSERT into foo
VALUES
(1,'Name', 'Carl'),
(1,'Jobtitle', 'Driver'),
(2,'Name', 'Lisa'),
(2,'Age', '15'),
(3,'Name', 'Jon'),
(3,'Age', '43'),
(3,'Jobtitle  ', 'Programmer')

SELECT e.id, STUFF((SELECT  ', ' + attribute+'='+value
     FROM foo EE
     WHERE  EE.id=E.id

 FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS listStr

FROM foo E
GROUP BY E.id
```